# Automatic module's name does not get recognized

Tags: java, migration, java-9

I have the task to migrate a project from JDK8 to JDK9. It is currently not needed to go for a full migration to jigsaw modules. However, in one of the project's packages the java.xml.ws package is being used, which, as you know, is not accessible unless you specify it in a module-info file (using the --add-modules workaround is not an option). So I declared the package as a separate module and have no problems with the java.xml.ws package.

However, the newly created module needs access to two other modules in my project (loaded from the classpath), but they are currently not visible.

I read, that automatic modules could be used for such a purpose. However, I cannot find the automatic module's name. There is no name in the MANIFEST.MF file. When I specify one, I am still not able to declare the dependency in the module-info file. The automatic module name does not get recognized.

Has anybody come across a similar issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to share a reproducible example for that. Not really clear what is working and what is not working for you without a sample.

Comment: Only jar files can be automatic modules. Alternatively, when you say "loaded from the classpath", have you checked that these other 'modules' are really on the classpath not no the module path?